# Cascaded batch validation

Tags: hibernate-validator

Is it possible to make a batched validation of annotated fields?

For example, we have a class

```
class SomeContainer {

@Valid
List<InnerClass> innerClass;
}

class InnerClass {

@CustomValidator
String validated;

@Valid
NestedClass nestedClass;

}

class NestedClass {

@CustomValidator
String validateToo;
}
```

And when we validate SomeContainer. Validator collect all fields with @CustomValidator and make a some batch (aggregated validation) and if something is wrong the whole SomeContainer object is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You should try it :)

It's how cascaded validation works. See our documentation here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-object-graph-validation

> The validation of object graphs is recursive, i.e. if a reference marked for cascaded validation points to an object which itself has properties annotated with @Valid, these references will be followed up by the validation engine as well. The validation engine will ensure that no infinite loops occur during cascaded validation, for example if two objects hold references to each other.

Comment: thanks, for the answer! i saw it. but i want to collect all fields, what needs  validate, and after what, make some aggregate validation.